Misunderstanding of Einstein Summation Convention
If I sum two matrices:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}x_i^2 + M_{ij}\tag{1}
$$
Simplifying the first term:
$$
2x_j \delta_{ij} + M_{ij}\tag{2}
$$
I then become confused if I use the Dirac-Delta summation trick:
$$
2x_j + M_{ij}\tag{3}
$$
I now have the sum of a vector and a matrix. Oops.
Where am I going wrong ?
Equation 1) First term has a single i and single j, so must be a matrix.
Equation 2) The presence of two j's seems to imply they are summed over, but then we no longer have a matrix.
I suspect there must be some rule I am not following in my use of ESN. If I instead use explicit summation notation I arrive at the correct answer.
UPDATE
Thankyou to @greg for providing the answer in terms of the 3rd order kronecker-delta. However, I have encountered a generalisation of the above problem which I am still unable to solve.
The expression I seek to evaluate is:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial I_{lm}} e^{V_{ij}I_{jk}W_k}
$$
In attempting to solve this, I first attempt a simpler problem:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_l} e^{C_{jk}W_k}
$$
By employing a higher order kronecker delta, I proceed as follows. The resultant quantity is only non-zero when $W_k = W_l$, thus I suspect a kronecker to be of use. The resultant quantity will have 2 indices, $l$ and $j$, so I set these as the first indices of my delta:
$$
\Theta_{lj}
$$
The derivative extracts a coefficient of $C_{jk}$ giving:
$$
\Theta_{ljmn}C_{mn}
$$
And finally, the remaining exponential:
$$
\Theta_{ljmno}C_{mn}e^{C_{ok}W_k}
$$
This is a two index object, whose value is only non-zero when all indices in the expression:
$$
C_{mn}e^{C_{ok}W_k}
$$
are equal, which seems to be correct. Any feedback if I am on the right track would be appreciated. Based on this result, I expect the expression:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial I_{lm}} e^{V_{ij}I_{jk}W_k}
$$
to be as follows. First, write a kronecker with the dimension of the desired result, in this case 3 indices
$$
\Theta_{ijk}
$$
Next, add the coefficients
$$
\Theta_{ijklmn}V_{lm}W_{n}
$$
Finally, add the exponential
$$
\Theta_{ijklmno}V_{lm}W_{n}e^{V_{op}I_{pq}W_q}
$$
This is the best I have arrived at so far. However, I am not entirely sure my treatement of the differentiated variables contracted index is correct. Perhaps there should be an additional $\delta_{ab}$ in there somewhere ? Guidance and a second opinion is appreciated.
Update II
After some further testing by explicitly writing down tensor entries, I have come to the following:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial I_{lm}} e^{V_{ij}I_{jk}W_k} = \Theta_{iab}V_{al}W_{m}e^{V_{bc}I_{cd}W_d}
$$
In arriving at this quantity, I have used the reasoning:

If a derivative would act to duplicate an index, as in $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a} sin(W_{bc}x_c) $, the result must contain a kronecker-delta that 'links' these two indices.

Again, I am not certain on this, so guidance is appreciated.

The derivative is just $2x_j \delta_{ij}$, full stop, and there is no summation involved or implied at all. (This is exactly why I don't like the Einstein summation convention!)

The resultant matrix will have $2x_i+M_{ii}$ on its diagonal and $M_{ij}$ on its off-diagonal.

You're simply doing scalar operations on one of the coordinates of this matrix resulting from the sum of these two, no summation involved.

There is another (almost) mistake. Since you start with $x_i^2$ you need to keep the $i$ and end up with $2x_i\delta_{ij} + M_{ij}$. If $\delta$ were not a diagonal matrix, this would not be the same thing as $2x_j\delta_{ij} + M_{ij}$ unless $M$ were symmetric.

Thankyou for your comment @NicholasTodoroff . The question I have is not about this problem specifically, but regarding the general misconception I am following. This is outlined in the update I have added - what is a general rule to follow in such instances to preserve the integrity of ESC, where the derivative may act linearly on a quantity ?

What you're doing is seeing a summation when there is none.
Summations in the ESC are when you have indicies which do not match on each side of an equation.  Like this:
$$u_i=a_{ij}v^j$$
which is an implied sum over $j$ elements on the right hand side.
However you have something more like:
$$b_{ij}=a_{i}b_{ij}$$
There are no un-matched indices on either side to imply a summation.

$
\def\c{\cdot}
\def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\H{{\Theta}}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\blue{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Recall that the Hadamard (or element-wise) product of two vectors commutes
$$\eqalign{
p &= a\h b \;=\; b\h a \\
}$$
and that it can be eliminated in favor of diagonal matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= \Diag a, \; B= \Diag b \qiq p = Ab \;=\; Ba \\
}$$
which makes the differential and gradient of the product easy to calculate
$$\eqalign{
dp &= A\,db + B\,da &\qiq\grad pa = B = \Diag b \\
&&\qiq \grad pb = A = \Diag a \\
}$$
The current problem is recovered by setting $\,a=b=x\;$
$$\eqalign{
p_i &= x_i^2 \\
p &= x\h x \;=\; Xx &\qiq X=\Diag x \\
dp &= X\,dx+X\,dx &\qiq \grad px = 2X \\\\
}$$

Before translating this result into index notation, we must first introduce the third-order tensor analog of the Kronecker delta (which itself is a second-order tensor)
$$\eqalign{
\delta_{ij} &= \begin{cases}
\o \qq {\rm if}\q i=j \\
 0 \qq {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\qq{\Large\longrightarrow}\qq
\H_{ijk} &= \begin{cases}
\o \qq {\rm if}\q i=j=k \\
 0 \qq {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
}$$
The $\Theta$ tensor can be used to convert a vector into a diagonal matrix
(via a dot product)
$$\eqalign{
A &= \H\c a \qif A_{ij} &= \H_{ijk}\,a_{k} \\
}$$
or to convert the diagonal matrix back into a vector (via a double-dot product)
$$\eqalign{
a &= \H:A \qif a_{i} &= \H_{ijk}\,A_{jk} \\
}$$
More importantly, it can be used to express your troublesome gradient completely within the rules of the Einstein summation convention
$$\eqalign{
\grad px &= 2\,\H\c x \qif \grad{p_i}{x_j} = 2\,\H_{ijk}\,x_{k} \\
}$$
$(\,$TLDR: you should have used $\H$ instead of $\delta\,)$

I feel this is more of a comment but it has gotten too long.
Your analysis of $$\frac\partial{\partial W_l}e^{C_{jk}W_k}$$ makes no sense to me. Assuming $k$ is summed over, the result is $$C_{jl}e^{C_{jk}W_k}.\tag{$*$}$$ Einstein summation isn't some arcane system of symbol pushing. It's summation. That's it. I would encourage you to write out all summations explicitly until you get the hang of it; for example, assuming $k=1,2,3$ the above is simply $$\frac\partial{\partial W_l}e^{C_{j1}W_1+C_{j2}W_2+C_{j3}W_3}.$$ The names of the symbols don't matter; we could rename $W_1,W_2,W_3$ to $x,y,z$. Then this looks like $$\frac\partial{\partial x}e^{C_{j1}x+C_{j2}y+C_{j3}z},\quad \frac\partial{\partial y}e^{C_{j1}x+C_{j2}y+C_{j3}z},\quad \frac\partial{\partial z}e^{C_{j1}x+C_{j2}y+C_{j3}z}.$$
Using this sort of mental image is how I arrived at ($*$).
If you want something more mechanical, then go step-by-step:
$$
  \frac\partial{\partial W_l}e^{C_{jk}W_k} \overset1= e^{C_{jk}W_k}\frac\partial{\partial W_l}(C_{jm}W_m) \overset2= e^{C_{jk}W_k}C_{jm}\frac\partial{\partial W_l}W_m \overset3= e^{C_{jk}W_k}C_{jm}\delta_{lm} \overset4= e^{C_{jk}W_k}C_{jl}
$$

We use the chain rule: $\frac\partial{\partial x}e^{f(x)} = e^{f(x)}\frac\partial{\partial x}f(x)$. Each occurrence of $f(x)$ must be the same quantity. In this case, with $k=1,2,3$ and $l=1$, $$f(W_1) = C_{j1}W_1+C_{j2}W_2+C_{j3}W_3.$$ This means $$\frac\partial{\partial W_1}e^{f(W_1)} = e^{C_{j1}W_1+C_{j2}W_2+C_{j3}W_3}\frac\partial{\partial W_1}(C_{j1}W_1+C_{j2}W_2+C_{j3}W_3).$$ This is not the same thing as $$\color{red}{e^{C_{jk}W_k}\frac\partial{\partial W_l}(C_{jk}W_k)}.$$ This is why we need to introduce another summed index $m$.
This is simply applying the linearity of differentiation.
This is evaluating the derivative.
Because $m$ is being summed over we contract $C_{jm}$ with $\delta_{lm}$ to get $C_{jl}$.

